# Java StandardFileManager: File not found

Tags: java

I want to dynamically compile java code with the following code:

```
private void loadLevelFromFile() {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("D:\\Level.java"));
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);
        boolean success = task.call();
        try {
            fileManager.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Success returns `false` and when investigating the messages from the `DiagnosticCollector` I get the following:

```
[error: error reading D:\Level.java; D:\Level.java (The system can't find the specified file]
```

The file exists at the specified location. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check the permissions on the file? Might be a permissions issue...

Comment: Thannks for your input it wasn't the permissiosn but I didn't notice the system I'm working on hides file extensions.. so this was the issue. Thank you!